# Мета-тег <meta name="robots">

Tags: html

Если разместить код `<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">` внутри `<body>`, не проигнорируют ли его поисковые роботы?

Answer (score 1):

Проигнорируют, ибо:

> Элемент `<head>` предназначен для хранения других элементов, цель
>   которых — помочь браузеру в работе с данными. Также внутри контейнера
>   `<head>` находятся метатеги, которые используются для хранения
>   информации предназначенной для браузеров и поисковых систем.
>
> Элемент `<meta>` определяет метатеги, которые используются для хранения
>   информации предназначенной **для** браузеров и **поисковых систем**. Например,
>   механизмы поисковых систем обращаются к метатегам для получения
>   описания сайта, ключевых слов и других данных. Разрешается
>   использовать более чем один метатег, **все они размещаются в контейнере
>   `<head>`.**

Источник: [тег head](https://webref.ru/html/head) и [тег meta](https://webref.ru/html/meta)